# Time complexity of a recursive function, using the Master's Theorem

Tags: time-complexity, pseudocode

I need to find the time complexity of the function in the picture using Master's Theorem..
I think the function is: T(n) = T(n-1) + c but it's impossible to solve using this theorem.

[The function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X2j9Q.png)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a mathematics question (solving a recurrence), not a computer programming question.

Answer (score 0):

The Master's theorem is for recurrences of the form T(n) = a*T(n/b) + f(n), where a >= 1 and b > 1 are constants.

Your recurrence is T(n) = T(n-1) + c, where c >= 1 is a constant.

n - 1 can't be put in the form n / b with b constant. So it's impossible to use Master's theorem here.

But it can be easily proved by induction that your recurrence gives T(n) = c * n as result.

---

Proof:

Let T(n) = c * n. You clearly have T(1) = T(0) + c = c * 0 + c = c , which is the base case.

Suppose it's valid for a given n, you have T(n+1) = T(n) + c = c * n + c = c * (n+1), so it's also valid for n + 1 and by induction it's valid for all natural number n.

Answer (score 0):

Let b equal base and p equal power.
Studying the algorithm in the photo the recurrence should be

T(n) = T(n-1) + O(log b^(p-1))
= T(n-1) + O(n)

due to the space occupied by f(n-1). See if you can use Master theorem now